How can I ensure that bookmarklets made on bullet points don't overlap when we update them?
I have a doc with a lot of bookmarks that I need to update automatically via VBA Excel, so I have bullets point that go with bookmarks, as below.
-   Fixe_2 
-   Fixe_3:

o   Fixe_4
o   Fixe_5

But when I update the bookmarks it overlaps for example for fix_4 = blablalbla
the bookmarks of fix_5 take position on the bullet point that was fix_4.
-   Fixe_2 
-   Fixe_3:

o   BalblablaFixe_5

Here is the simplified code I use to update my bookmarks
      If Range("G10") = "Fixe" Then
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_2").Range.Text = "Blablabla "
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_3").Range.Text = " Blablabla"
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_4").Range.Text = " Blablabla "
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_5").Range.Text = " Blablabla "
      Else
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_2").Range.Text = ""
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_3").Range.Text = " "
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_4").Range.Text = " "
         wdDoc.Bookmarks("Fixe_5").Range.Text = " "


Are the bullet points properly formatted, i.e., they are set with Styles? In that case you could try and search for their level, else you could try and see at the indentation or the special character in use. It would be helpful to add some more information: right now it is quite hard to understand the scope of the macro and the limitations you are encountering.

It would help to see how you've set up the bookmarks in an actual document, but my guess is that your bookmarks include the paragraph mark at the end of each line. Then, when you update the text, the paragraph mark is replaced by the text and the text becomes part of the following paragraph.
Fix this by making paragraph marks visible using File>Options>Display and checking the option for Paragraph marks. Then replace the bookmarks with ones that only encompass the text.
Bookmarks are relatively fragile and easily deleted. You might consider replacing them with Content Controls, then filling the controls with text using a macro. Something like:
Dim oCC As ContentControl

For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If oCC.Title = "Fixe 2 Control" Then
        oCC.Range.Text = "Blablabla"
    End If
Next oCC


Why would you loop through all the content controls instead of using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytitle or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytag?
